# Could Draco have wished up a tunnel to the outside world in the Room of Requirement?

Tags: harry-potter

In *The Deathly Hallows*, Neville reveals how he managed to create a tunnel between the Room of Requirement and Hogsmeade:

> "It's quite straightforward, really," said Neville modestly.  "I'd been in here about a day and a half, and getting really hungry, and wishing I could get something to eat, and that's when the passage to the Hog's Head opened up.  I went through it and met Aberforth.  He's been providing us with food, because for some reason, that's the one thing the room doesn't do.

Inspired by [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123818/who-created-the-tunnel-between-the-room-of-requirement-and-hogsmead#comment307163_123820): could Draco Malfoy have created such a tunnel in *The Half Blood Prince*? Could he have simply thought "Man, this vanishing cabinet stuff isn't working out. I really wish there was another way for the Death Eaters to waltz into Hogwarts" and then a tunnel would be created?

Comment: Yes, yes he could have. Which is really dumb, but there you go.

Comment: We don't know whether the tunnel can go further than Hogsmeade.

Comment: @Valorum Can't the Room of Requirement really just summon anything (besides the exceptions to Gamp's Law)? New profile pic?

Comment: @INTERESTING - Actually this is about my 30th profile pic. They tend to be variations on a theme, I just don't think you've been active long enough to see a change

Comment: @Valorum True. I've been around 2 months. :)

Comment: But the Death Eaters would not necessarily be able to enter through Hogsmeade

Comment: Isn't that essentially what the pair of the Vanishing Cabinets provide?

Comment: @ivanivan Draco went bananas to make the Vanishing Cabinets work. This just makes him look stupid. Which he is in many ways but in this case, it looks like a plot error.

Comment: @Matte Voldemort obsessed over Harry, and we all know how stupid that was, in hindsight. I think it's good character development - wizards don't seem very open minded or good at lateral thinking, especially purebloods.

Comment: marcellothearcane You mean, it was good character development for Draco? Voldemort's obsession with Harry was stupid perhaps but it was justified. He feared death and Harry was prophesized to be his death. Draco is a formidable opponent despite everything. He spent an year working on the Cabinets. Neville wished for some food and he got the tunnel. I believe Draco would definitely have wished for something that could lead the Death eaters to Hogwarts. With his family's life on the line, it's not that far fetched to think he did. So maybe it's a plot hole or there's a good explanation for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## There's no reason it shouldn't...

The Room of Requirement doesn't discriminate between Death Eaters and... non-Death Eaters. Therefore, Draco wishing for a passage should have the same effect as Neville (indirectly) wishing for one. Even if the tunnel had to be an existing one, the one that Neville used would suffice (and the Death Eaters would take out Aberforth and use the tunnel. So, really, anybody should be able to open a passage to an outside place.

Answer (score 2):

If Draco had thought "Man, this vanishing cabinet stuff isn't working out. I really wish there was another way for the Death Eaters to waltz into Hogwarts" inside the Room of Requirement, it definitely would have created a tunnel to somewhere outside, possibly Malfoy Manor.

But, the thing is: He didn't. And, it didn't occur to him that he could use the Room of Requirement in such a way or that such a thing was even possible because of Hogwarts' security (creativity is mysterious thing). Even Neville got the tunnel accidentally.